# Show that $(1_n+B)^{-1}=1_n-B+B^2-\ldots+(-1)^{n-1}B^{n-1}.$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider the following exercise:

Let $B$ be a an upper triangular matrix such that $b_{ij}=0$ for $i\geq j$. Show that $B^n=0$, and deduce that $$(1_n+B)^{-1}=1_n-B+B^2-\ldots+(-1)^{n-1}B^{n-1}.$$

I have proved that $B^n=0$, however I haven't been able to prove the last equality. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**Note:** $1_n$ denotes the identity matrix.

Comment: Use the definition of inverse. RHS multipied by $1_n+B$ on either side gives you $1_n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Idea**:
By the definition, $A=( 1_n+B)^{-1}$ is the only matrix such that:
$$A( 1_n+B)= 1_n$$
so ....

Answer (score 1):

In any ring with unit (commutative or not) $A$, one has

$$\forall a\in A, \forall k, 1-a^k=(1-a)\left(1+a+a^2+\cdots+a^{k-1}\right)$$

Just use this identity in the ring of matrices with $a=-B$ and $k=n$.